# Why do I get an IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, list, arraylist, error-handling, index-error

In my code I am getting an index error - IndexError: list index out of range. Could you please 1) explain why is this and then 2) make some corrections to my code? Thank you for your answer in advance

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] % 2 == 0:
        del x[i]
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Do not delete items from a list you're currently iterating over - use a list comprehension instead.

Comment: delete items while you are iterating over it - is super bad idea :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a new list (comprehension) instead:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

y = [item for item in x if not item % 2 == 0]
print(y)
# [1, 3, 5]
```

Or - considered "more pythonic":

```
y = [item for item in x if item % 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `del` you reduce the size of your array but the initial loop goes through the initial size of the array, hence the IndexError.

If you want to delete items I recommend using list comprehension:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

x_filtered = [i for i in x if i%2]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are removing objects inside of the loop, in other words making the list shorter.

Instead use this:

```
x = x[0::2]
```

To select every second value of the list

If you want all the even vaues, instead use a list generator:

```
x = [value for value in x in value%2 == 0]
```

Comment: He wants to remove items that are even not indexes that are even

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting items from the very list you are iterating over. An alternative approach would be:

```py
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
answer = [i for i in x if i % 2 != 0]

print(answer)
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i in range(len(x) -1, -1, -1):
    if x[i] % 2 == 0:
        x.pop(i)
```

"range function takes three arguments.

First is the start index which is [length of list – 1], that is, the index of last list element(since index of list elements starts from 0 till length – 1).

Second argument is the index at which to stop iteration.

Third argument is the step size.
Since we need to decrease index by 1 in every iteration, this should be -1." - [Source](https://codippa.com/how-to-remove-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python/)

I highly recommend list comprehension however in certain circumstances there is no point and removing through iteration is fine. Up to you~

Answer (score 0):

use while loop instead of for loop if you want to delete some item.

```
    x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    i = 0
    while i<len(x):
        if x[i]%2==0:
            del x[i]
        i+=1
    print(x)
```